Setting a property value via reflection on an object referenced by a collection, with a different view, throws an exception
I was using BindingList<T> in my ViewModel, in an MVVM pattern with Windows Forms on .NET 8.0, and then I created a generic function that would fetch a key field in the list. Since I use the same property to edit and fetch the value of the key field, if the item is not found I restore the original value of the key field, and for that I use reflection, calling PropertyInfo.SetValue() on the current item:
   public BindingListView<TDetailViewModel> Items;
   public TDetailViewModel? CurrentItem;

   protected PropertyInfo mDetailKeyFieldPropInfo;

   private void SearchKeyFieldValue()
   {
      var currentFieldValue = this.mDetailKeyFieldPropInfo.GetValue(this.CurrentItem);
      var originalFieldValue = this.CurrentItem.OriginalKeyFieldValue;

      var foundItem = this.Items
                            .Where(item => item.OriginalKeyFieldValue.Equals(currentFieldValue))
                            .FirstOrDefault();
      if (foundItem != null)
      {
         this.CurrentItem = foundItem;
      }
      else
      {
         mDialogService.ShowWarningMessage("Item not found.");
         this.mDetailKeyFieldPropInfo.SetValue(this.CurrentItem, originalFieldValue);
      }
   }

It was working fine.
But I needed filtering and sorting capabilities. So I created a BindingListView<T> class, implementing IBindingListView interface, using the following concept: when the collection is filtered or sorted, I present the same original collection, but with a different view, for this I store a list with the original indexes of the objects. For example, when a filtered and/or sorted list requests the first element in the collection, it actually points to the 6th element in the source collection, so that is the object I return. I was very inspired by FilteredBindingList and SortedBindingList from Rockford Lhotka's CSLA .NET framework. I then changed the type of the list items from BindingList<T> to the new BindingListView<T>.
After that the search function still works. But, if I filter the list, let's say the list has 6 items and after filtering it has only 1 item, if I search for an item that is not in the filtered list, the following error occurs when calling PropertyInfo.SetValue() on the current item:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: 'Exception has been
thrown by the target of an invocation.'
Inner Exception
ArgumentOutOfRangeException: rowIndex ('3') must be less than '1'. Arg_ParamName_Name
ArgumentOutOfRange_ActualValue

So, it seems that it is working directly on the list and cannot find the row index. But the strange thing is that the CurrentItem property only references the object that is in the list, so I don't understand where this attempt to access some index of the list comes from.
The exact same problem occurs if I try to use PropertyDescriptor.SetValue() instead.
What could be the cause of this?
